# Blackberry: FileSystemJournalListener not returning the newly captured image path

Tags: java, blackberry

**FileSystemJournalListener not returning the newly captured image path.
 My camera saves images to sdcard/blackberry/pictures/...**

But listener give me blank image path at
store/home/user/pictures/Image_1337710522032.jpg

and actual saved file is at 
sdcard/BlackBerry/pictures/IMG00010-20111019-1225.jpg

How am I supposed the set FileSystemJournalListener to scan the sdcard for the newly added image path ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the code for your listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the appropriate example to follow](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Detect_when_img_is_added_or_removed_file_system_740288_11.jsp) from the BlackBerry developer documentation.

In the app I have that does this, my `FileSystemJournalListener` looks like the code below.  You have to iterate over USNs to find the new image.

You can also [see this page](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/FileSystemJournal.html) for more information about `FileSystemJournal` and how to check for new files.

```
public class FileSystemListener implements FileSystemJournalListener, Runnable {
       /** The last USN to have to search until, when looking for new files added to the file system */
       private long _lastUSN;
       /** The filename of the new image */
       private String _imageFilename;

       public void run() {
          // TODO: do something with the new image
       }

       public FileSystemListener() {
          // we record the next system USN before the Camera app has a chance to add a new file
          _lastUSN = FileSystemJournal.getNextUSN();
       }

       public void fileJournalChanged() {
          long nextUSN = FileSystemJournal.getNextUSN();
          boolean imgFound = false;
          // we have to search for the file system event that is the new image
          for (long lookUSN = nextUSN - 1; (lookUSN >= _lastUSN) && !imgFound; --lookUSN) {
             FileSystemJournalEntry entry = FileSystemJournal.getEntry(lookUSN);
             if (entry == null) {
                break;
             } else {
                String path = entry.getPath();
                if (path != null) {
                   if (path.endsWith("png") || path.endsWith("jpg") || path.endsWith("bmp") || path.endsWith("gif")) {
                      switch (entry.getEvent()) {
                         case FileSystemJournalEntry.FILE_ADDED:
                            // either a picture was taken or a picture was added to the BlackBerry device
                            _lastUSN = lookUSN;
                            _imageFilename = path;
                            imgFound = true;

                            // unregister for file system events?
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().removeFileSystemJournalListener(this);

                            // let this callback complete before responding to the new image event
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(this);
                            break;
                         case FileSystemJournalEntry.FILE_DELETED:
                            // a picture was removed from the BlackBerry device;
                            break;
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.
Can above code detect the images added on sdcard ? or it only tracks the internal memory filesystem changes ?

Comment: @user1407894, Yes the code above can detect images added to the SDCard.  I just ran the app I built that uses this code to test it.  It works for internal storage or the SDCard.  Obviously, the paths will be different for those two locations (`String path =`).  But, yes, it does detect files on the media card.

Comment: Thanks dude. :)
will check it now.

Comment: @user1407894.  No problem.  I will also just point out that my code above only finds one image.  After it finds the new image, it stops listening for more file system events.  This was correct for my app, but might not be correct for yours.  Anyway, you can delete my call to `removeFileSystemJournalListener` if you want your app to keep waiting for more images.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable  comment :)